# Функция exif_read_data не отдает данные Orientation

Tags: php

Добрый день!
В php есть функция `exif_read_data`, которая должна отдавать информацию о изображении. При обработке изображения, загруженного со смартфона, функция не возвращает `IFD0`.
В чем может быть проблема?
Вызываю так:

```
$source = exif_read_data('../files/ogorod/3189.jpg', 0, true);
print_r($source) ;
```

Результат:

```
Array ( 
    [FILE] => Array (
        [FileName] => 3189.jpg 
        [FileDateTime] => 1486467789 
        [FileSize] => 68085 
        [FileType] => 2 
        [MimeType] => image/jpeg 
        [SectionsFound] => COMMENT
     )
     [COMPUTED] => Array (
        [html] => width="1000" height="750" 
        [Height] => 750 
        [Width] => 1000 
        [IsColor] => 1
     )
     [COMMENT] => Array (
         [0] => CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v80), quality = 70                        
      )
)
```

Comment: пробовали явно указать, чтобы читал `IFD0` ?

Comment: уверены ли вы, что изображение точно содержит эти данные

Comment: да, так тоже пробовал, пустой ответ $source = exif_read_data('../files/ogorod/3189.jpg', 'IFD0');

Comment: изображение сделано со смартфона 100% мной, думаю, что при move_uploaded_file данные не теряются.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.
После move_uploaded_file шел ресайз изображения, поэтому данные **IFD0** терялись. Всем спасибо.